# How to distribute a shared library to developers

Tags: java

We have 20 developers distributed across 4 teams on one geographical location.

Every developer has a identical configured development environment consisting of Eclipse, Java and Tomcat.

All the development done by these developers (several hundred java projects) share common logic which we have put into a eclipse project. This project's source is in SCM.

Only a few developers develop the common logic and therefore need to check out/in changes to the common project.

All the developers need a copy of the compiled JAR file to store into their tomcat\lib folder.

How do we best:

1. Notify developers that a new common JAR has been published ?
2. Update the JAR in tomcat\lib folder and refresh eclipse
   workspace/java compiler to reflect the changes ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use Maven (a tutorial is [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/maven/)).  Your common logic can be distributed as a JAR file with a `pom.xml` describing them as a Maven artifact.  You may also assign version to your JAR file.

Your developers' projects also will have their own `pom.xml` which declares a dependency on the the above artifact.

Comment: I'd prefer not to introduce Maven just for this. Maven is a great tool, but serves a greater purpose than my need and more complexity than I need. I was hoping for a simpler solution within Eclipse, Tomcat, Windows or another currently existing component